# TokBox one-to-one Text & Video Chat - Android

Tags: text, chat, opentok, videochat, tokbox

As per our client need in mobile application the Publisher needs to initiate the session and show the text chat first and same as when a Subscriber joins the session, he starts with the text chat. If the subscriber wants to start & join video chat, he can ask the publisher and starts the video chat once publisher accepts & started.

Now the issue is if the Publisher initiates the session & press home button. App does not gets internet service, due to this the session disconnects after few auto reconnecting try outs.
So we planned to re-initiate the same session with same session id & token, once the Publisher resumes the app.
In this latest sample app (https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-android) we could not able to re-initiate the session. But in the previous example with the following package compile 'com.opentok.android:accelerator-pack:+' we can achieve connecting to session, But the text chat session is not connecting.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push HOME button should not cut internet connection. Actually, normal behaviour is to keep audio streaming so you have to mute it on onPause()

If you are suffering disconnections for any reason and you can't solve it, you should not try to reuse a session. It is recommended to create a new one.